# How can I add a border image to a dynamically created image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, border

I am pulling an image from an ajax call and trying to add it to an established div.  The div already includes an image I'd like to use as a border.  The problem is, when I use jQuery to HTML the image into said div, it takes the place of the border instead of occupying the same place.  I understand why.  However, when I create a div nested inside the aforementioned div and try to position it behind the border-image (which works) the image does not resize well with the border.

I have tried adding a 'border-image: url(./image.png)' but that does not want to work.  Is there any way I can combine the image and border with JQuery before posting it to the html, or is there a better way to do this with CSS?

I have tried adding a 'border-image: url(./image.png)' but that does not want to work.

```
<div class="col s2" id="facePlate1">
<img src="./imageFrame.png">  
<div id="firstActor"></div>     
</div>

$("#firstActor").html(`<img class= "gifControl" src="${conc}"  alt="Gif"> 
</div>`)
```

I would like the firstActor image to appear behind the border-image.

Comment: Could you post your css as well?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you shouldn't add another closing div tag in your jQuery function. The firstActor div is already closed. If that's correct, your new HTML will look something like this:

```
<div class="col s2" id="facePlate1">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150">  
  <div id="firstActor">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
  </div>     
</div>
```

And assuming that you want to position one picture over the over, so that it looks like a frame, you could do that with the following css

```
#facePlate1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
#firstActor {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  transform: translate(100%,100%);
}
```

codepen here: https://codepen.io/MortenDL/pen/dyyXdgW

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this by making the border image the background of the image's wrapper like this:

```css
#frame{
  background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/200);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#image{
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <img id="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/180">
</div>
```